# VS 2017 and Selenium.Webdriver NuGet: chromedriver.exe not found

Tags: selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-2017, selenium-chromedriver

I've been using the NuGet packages for Selenium Webdriver in Visual Studio 2015 with great success. Instead of downloading the chromedriver.exe file and adding it manually, I've done everything via NuGet.

Now, in VS 2017, this doesn't work anymore.

I've added all the necessary NuGet packages: Selenium.WebDriver (3.11.1) and Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver (2.37.0).

However, when I try to instantiate the driver and open Chrome, I get the following exception:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException: 'The chromedriver.exe file
does not exist in the current directory or in a directory on the PATH 
environment variable. The driver can be downloaded at 
http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html.'
```

The whole point for using NuGet (at least in this case) is to NOT download and add the driver manually. But why is this broken?

For cleanliness sake, here is the test code I'm using to instantiate chromedriver:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

class Program {
    public static IWebDriver Instance { get; set; }
    static void Main (string[] args) {
        var driverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();      
        driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
        Instance = new ChromeDriver(driverService);

        Instance.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.nrk.no");
    }
}
```

NB: This is an exact piece of the code I've been using in Visual Studio 2015, so the code SHOULD work normally.

And I know that some people believes that it's better to add chromedriver.exe manually, but I tried that - by Add - Existing Item (and Copy if newer). That doesn't work either; I get the same exception.

Comment: I’d just like to point out that I know of no browser driver executable maintainers (chromedriver.exe, geckodriver.exe,IEDriverServer.exe) that provides and maintains an official NuGet package for their executable. The .NET bindings’ algorithm for automatically finding such executables is pretty simple. If a specific path is specified, use that. If not, look for the executable in the same directory as the assembly containing the `FileUtilities` class. If it’s not found there, look in each directory in the `PATH` environment variable. It’s possible VS2017 changed where filed get copied on build.

Comment: You can  try setting copy local to true for chromedriver.exe . If that doesn't work, consider adding a post build command to copy chromedriver.exe to your bin folder. It might be possible that trying to add the nuget package in vs2017 is not doing some required step which was done in vs2015 for reasons such as the package source is different in each case or the script is not updated to target vs2017.

Comment: JimEvans: I'm testing this with a small console project that just instantiates Selenium Webdriver and opens a browser and url. The chromedriver.exe IS located in the following folder after build: C:\Source\Workspaces\QA\Opus3FlowAutomation\SeleniumTest\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0. Which is as it should, since I'm debugging. However, it still claims that the chromedriver.exe isn't found.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed from your comments that you were building for .Net Core.  I was having a similar problem where ChromeDriver.exe would end up in the bin dir after build, but it wouldn't be available in the publish folder using dotnet publish, so when I deploy using publish, ChromeDriver.exe wouldn't get copied from the build output directory.  If you are experiencing the same problem, or if you don't like the work-around you already did and want to fix it, then you can do what I did:

Edit the project file of the web driver project you are building to set a property named **PublishChromeDriver** = true. It will look something like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <ApplicationIcon />
    <StartupObject />
    <NeutralLanguage>en</NeutralLanguage>
    <GenerateSerializationAssemblies>Off</GenerateSerializationAssemblies>

    <!-- Add the following line -->
    <PublishChromeDriver>true</PublishChromeDriver>

  </PropertyGroup>
...
```

I suppose you could set the property at the build/publish command line as ***/p:PublishChromeDriver=true*** (should work to insert property via build/publish arguments in Azure DevOps, for instance).

The comments on [this NuGet issue](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4837) related to files in NuGet packages not getting published out led me to looking at the [ChromeDriver targets file](https://github.com/jsakamoto/nupkg-selenium-webdriver-chromedriver/blob/c9dae061ff521328430cd855cad314cf6aa33aed/src/Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver.targets#L13) and finding it there.

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem and fixed it. 
first, when you create a new project, you need to select C#->.net (or .net standard) as the project type.
Second, after the new project is created, you could use nuget to install selenium webdriver successfully.

Comment: That fixed it for me. It seems that the latest version of Selenium is not suited for .NET Framework?